# can we deploy a specific folder inside GitHub repository?

Tags: github, deployment, repository

I have made a repository on Github "Front-end Projects". The plan is to make front-end projects with different difficulty levels. Hence, the repository is going to have many nested folders.

Now, the problem is I am trying to deploy a folder of a website I created on netlify but I cannot access the folder but only the repository. Is there any way to deploy these projects?

My folder hierarchy is like this. "Front-end Project" is the Repository I pushed on GitHub:

[image: Folder hierarchy]

Answer (score 1):

For [Netlify support](https://answers.netlify.com/t/support-guide-what-if-my-project-folder-is-not-the-root-of-my-git-repository/123/19)

> There are some projects that live in a folder instead of the root of your git repository.
>
> If you need to deploy your site from a subdirectory, there are two ways to do it:
>
> 1. You can set this in the UI:
>    [image: https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/netlify/original/2X/7/763e3be54cbcfa9187754c7626816ed69a8ddf66.png]
>
> In your site dashboard for the specific site you want to configure, go to `Settings > Build & deploy > build-settings`.
> The option is labeled `Base directory`.
>
> 2. Or, your can use a [`netlify.toml` file](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/file-based-configuration/) and set the base dir:
>
> ```
> [build]
>  base    = "subdirectory"
>  publish = "subdirectory/dist/"
>  command = "your build command"
> ```
>
> Now, your builds will work from the subdirectory folder mentioned above! If you have any issues, comment below.
>
> Note that enabling the base setting can have other effects on your site, which are described in [this article](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2019/10/09/launching-monorepo-support-for-netlify-sites/#we-ve-just-made-monorepos-easy-for-netlify-deployments) and in more detail in [our documentation](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/file-based-configuration/#ignore-builds).